# How to generate Authorization: Bearer token using RestAPI?

Tags: java, api, salesforce

I have Salesforce application admin username and password except client Id. I want to generate Authorization: Bearer token using RestAPI.  Can you please let me know How to generate Authorization: Bearer token using RestAPI ?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Salesforce api you need to use OAuth. Only a username and password are not enough to obtain an `Authorization: Bearer` token. [You can read all about it here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)